# item item-input: css styling, remove space in box

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm a newbie with both ionic, HTML and css. But I manage to do a simple web app.
But I am unable to style item-input class correctly. I search many forum but didn't found a correct solution.

I want to obtain 2 input feild look like clock: "Time:  : "
Mostly I was unable to remove the padding (or margin) at the right of each input field. Here a screenshot:
[image]

[EDIT]Sorry... forgot the code...

```
<label class="item item-input">          
        <span>Time </span>
        <input type="tel" maxlength='2' name="hour" min="0" max="23" ng-model="alarm.hour">
        <span> : </span>
        <input type="tel" maxlength='2' name="minute" min="0" max="59" ng-model="alarm.minute">
      </label>
      <br/>

      <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" style = "width: 320px; height: 8000px">
        <div ng-repeat="setpoint in alarm.setpoints track by $index">
        <div class = "scroll-container"></div>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">{{chName[$index]}}</span>
            <input type="tel" name="room" min="5" max="35" step="0.5" ng-model="alarm.setpoints[$index]">&#186;C
          </label>
        </div>
      </ion-scroll>
```

I got the same king of padding problem on temperature input with the celsius symbol offset to right...

Comment: create any code snippet ,No one can give idea with your screenshots

Comment: I keep trying to find a solution. did some troubleshooting on ionic.css  item-input to identify what function could cause it, I found that display: -webkit-box; and display: -webkit-flex are probably in cause. But I don't know what I could do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found what to do. ionic use flex to style app. For those newbie like me that incounter trouble like it, this video turorial help me a lot:
[flex tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg)

in addition. I found an other bug with ion-slides and scrool, and it generate some weird css trouble. And the solution is pretty simple: I jus add another 'ion-content' tag

```
<ion-view view-title="programs">
  <ion-content padding="true" >      
    <ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
      <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="alarm in alarms">
        <ion-content>    <!-- that's the add -->
          <div class="list">
```